# How can I minimize my PySimpleGUI program in system tray while keeping the program opened in background?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, pysimplegui

I have made a application in PySimpleGUI and it is working fine. Now I want to add the functionality in this so the user can run the program and minimize it into system tray. I have checked and found the following dummy code for creating system tray in PysimpleGUIWX :

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    System Tray Icon
    Your very own peronsal status monitor in your system tray
    Super easy to use.
    1. Find an icon file or use this default
    2. Create your menu defintion
    3. Add if statements to take action based on your input

"""

logo = b"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"

menu_def = ['UNUSED', ['My', 'Simple', '---', 'Menu', 'Exit']]
tray = sg.SystemTray(menu=menu_def, data_base64=logo)
tray.show_message('Starting', 'Now Starting the application')

while True:
    event = tray.read()
    if event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == 'Menu':       # add your checks here
        pass
    tray.show_message('Event', '{}'.format(event))
```

it is working fine and creating the system tray too but I am unable to understand that how I can use it or integrate it with my application.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For the tkinter port, a "small desktop icon" is the closest thing possible.  There have been a number of attempts to make a true system tray icon for the tkinter version of PySimpleGUI but isn't not there yet.